# Spring data Neo4j can't convert InternalNode back to entity class when retrieving paths

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm using Neo4jClient to do the following query for retrieving nodes and relationships by paths.

```
    public Collection<Map<String, Object>> findBookByUniqueIds(List<String> srcUniqueIds, String name) {

        return neo4jClient.query(
                        """
                                MATCH path = (src:Book)-[*1..2]-(target:Book)
                                WHERE src.uniqueId IN $uniqueIds
                                AND toUpper(target.name) = toUpper($name)
                                RETURN nodes(path) AS nodes, relationships(path) AS relations
                                """)
                .bind(srcUniqueIds).to("uniqueIds")
                .bind(name).to("name")
                .fetch().all();
    }
```

And I extract the data like this:

```
Collection<Map<String, Object>> result = findBookByUniqueIds(ids, name);
List<Object> nodes = (List<Object>) result.get("nodes");
List<Object> relationships = (List<Object>) result.get("relations");
```

When I was trying to cask the node back to entity class:

```
if (nodes.size() == 2) {
    Book book1 = (Book) nodes.get(0);
    Book book2 = (Book) nodes.get(1);
} else if (nodes.size() == 3) {
    Book book1 = (Book) nodes.get(0);
    Author author = (Author) nodes.get(1);
    Book book2 = (Book) nodes.get(2);
}
```

And I got the exception `java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalNode cannot be cast to class xxx`

Any idea on how to convert the node back to entity class?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm doing it right, but I've encountered this problem myself and haven't found a better solution than simply creating a new object of the class I need and populating it with values that I extract from the `InternalNode`.

For example:

```
InternalNode internalNode = (InternalNode) weightedCriteriaArrayElement.get("criterion");

Criterion criterion = new Criterion(); // my entity class
Map<String, Object> nodeProperties = new HashMap<>(internalNode.asMap());
BeanUtils.populate(criterion, nodeProperties);
criterion.setGraphId(internalNode.id());
```

Comment: I tried this way as well, but on one path, multiple nodes with different labels could be included. I have to manually check and convert each of them. Hope SDN could provide a more elegant way to deal with this.